# PHP class_name parameter of mysql_fetch_object() function

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm using `mysql_fetch_object` in my code, and am getting an error because the object I am trying to create an instance of has a constructor.

The error is as follows: `Warning: Missing argument 1 for Ratio::__construct() in /Users/Alex/Sites/All Good Things/_manage/c/c_ratio.php on line 9`

Which I can understand; here's the code for the `Ratio` constructor:

```
function __construct($new_name, $new_x, $new_y)
{
    $this->name = $new_name;
    $this->x = $new_x;
    $this->y = $new_y;
}
```

Anyway, how do I pass variables from the result I have just created to the function, ie, What I what to do is something like this:

```
while ($currentRatio = mysql_fetch_object(
                              $ratio_rs, 
                              'Ratio', 
                               array(
                                    <VALUE OF NAME>, 
                                    <VALUE OF X>, 
                                    <VALUE OF Y>)))
```

I can't find any examples of the syntax required for this third parameter.

Comment: The third parameter is an array of the constructor parameters, like you outlined it. Take care that the constructor will be called after the properties have been set from the database, not before. If `name` is a column, first the data will be fetched from the database, then the constructor will be called with your parameters and then `name` will be overwritten by your constructor code. Probably that's already intended, just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Column alias. Column alias depends on how you construct the query. If you use alias (by `as`) then it should be alias otherwise use the column name. See the example bellow.

```
$ratio_rs = mysql_query("SELECT Name, x as `X`, y as `Y` from ...");
mysql_fetch_object($ratio_rs, 
    'Ratio', 
    array(
        'Name', 
        'X', 
        'Y'
    )
);
```